# Trying to create single array of different class objects

Tags: c++, inheritance

I am required to create a base class worker with its attributes,
Create 2 classes ContractWorker and PartimeWorker that inherit from Worker class and 
Create an array that can hold 2 ContractWorker and 2  PartimeWorker objects.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstring>

using namespace std;

class worker
{

               int hrs;
               string name;
               int wage;
               public:
               worker():wage(200){}
             int pay(int hours)
             {
                 return(wage*hours);
             }
             worker (string nm,int hours)
             {
                    name=nm;
                    hrs=hours;
             };
};
class contract : public worker
{
      public:
             contract(){}
             void getsal(int hours)
             {
                      cout<<"\nSalary for "<<name<<" is "<<pay(hours);
                      cout<<"\nWorker is on contract\n";
             }
};
class part_time : public worker
{
      public:
             part_time(){}
             void getsal(int hours)
             {
                      cout<<"\nSalary for "<<name<<" is "<<pay(hours);
                      cout<<"\nWorker is part time\n";
             }
};
int main()
{
    worker *arr[4];
    string name="XYZ";
    int hours=10;

    arr[0]=new contract();
    arr[0].worker(name,hours);

    arr[1]=new contract();
    arr[1].worker(name,hours);

    arr[2]=new parttime();
    arr[2].parttime(name,hours);

    return 0;
}
```

Where exactly I am supposed to pass the values of name and hours attributes, in a function of derived classes or a function of base class?

And the following error 
51 request for member 'worker' in 'arr[0]', which is of pointer type 'worker*' (maybe you meant to use '->' ?) 
is showing up.

I am confused with the question. Please help.

Moreover how will the private members be accessible

Comment: Sorry..I am new here

Comment: No issue in being new, however you seem to need a good C++ primer on inheritance.

Comment: The error is correct - you're supposed to use "->", since the element `arr[0]` is a pointer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a lot of problems with your code. The main problem that you are experiencing is caused by the following lines.

```
arr[0].worker(name,hours);
arr[1].worker(name,hours);
arr[2].parttime(name,hours);
```

In order to access member functions through a pointer you need to use the `->` operator instead of `.`.  Unfortunately even that change will not work here as you cannot explicitly call the constructor of the base or derived class in this way.

There are some other problems with your code and some changes that you can make to address this.

- You need to include `<string>` instead of `<cstring>`
- `using namespace std;` is just bad form.
- the derived classes have no way to pass the name, wage, and hours to the base class during construction. This requires a constructor in the base class that takes the name, wage, and hours as arguments and will require the derived classes to do the same.
- The default constructor in the base class is probably not necessary for what you are trying to accomplish.
- There is no way for derived classes to access the member variables in the base class since they are private. I recommend adding an accessor function in the base class to retrieve the name.
- You are passing around a lot of strings by value when passing by `const` reference would be more appropriate. Although there is nothing inherently wrong with passing by value it creates unnecessary copies in this case.
- When you add the object pointers to the array you then try to initialize them by explicitly invoking the constructor of the base class. You cannot do this, constructors are special member functions that do not have names and cannot be called like that. You need to do this from the constructor of the derived classes.
- The `pay` member function would be better served if it was declared `const` since it does not modify any member variables.
- The `hours` member variable in the base class does not seem necessary since `pay` and `getsal` both take the hours as arguments.
- Your base class needs a virtual destructor.

Your code with most of the corrections listed above.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class worker
{
    std::string name;
    int wage;

public:

    //  constructor that takes name and wage by argument so member variables
    //  can be initialized during construction.
    worker(const std::string& name, int wage)
        : name(name), wage(wage)
    {
    }

    virtual ~worker() {}

    //  Declared const
    virtual int pay(int hours) const
    {
        return(wage*hours);
    }

    //  Added so base classes and free functions can access the name
    virtual const std::string& getName() const
    {
        return name;
    }

    //  Pure virtual requiring derived classes to provide a definition and
    //  allowing the function to be invoked through the base class interface.
    virtual void getsal(int hours) const = 0;
};

class contract : public worker
{
public:

    //  constructor that takes name and wage by argument so member variables
    //  can be initialized during construction.
    contract(const std::string& name, int wage)
        : worker(name, wage) {}

    void getsal(int hours) const
    {
        std::cout << "\nSalary for " << getName() << " is " << pay(hours);
        std::cout << "\nWorker is on contract\n";
    }
};

class part_time : public worker
{
public:

    //  constructor that takes name and wage by argument so member variables
    //  can be initialized during construction.
    part_time(const std::string& name, int wage)
        : worker(name, wage) {}

    void getsal(int hours) const
    {
        std::cout << "\nSalary for " << getName() << " is " << pay(hours);
        std::cout << "\nWorker is part time\n";
    }
};


int main()
{
    worker *arr[4];
    std::string name = "XYZ";
    int hours = 10;
    int wage = 100;

    //  construct the objects
    arr[0] = new contract(name, wage);
    arr[1] = new contract(name, wage);
    arr[2] = new part_time(name, wage);

    //  Calculate pay based on hours
    arr[0]->getsal(hours);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's work this from the ground up.

**Constructors**

In C++, a constructor is a special member function of the class having the same name as the class itself. Its role is to initialize the class data members.

For example:

```
class Word {
public:
    Word(std::string w): data(w) {}

    std::string data;
};
```

Here, `Word` is a class that may be constructed by passing it a `std::string` argument, which it uses to initialize its `data` data member.

- A class without any constructor declared has the compiler generating an implicit default constructor similar to `ClassName() {}`
- If a data member is not initialize in the *initializer list* (what comes between the `:` and the opening `{`), then it is default-initialize; beware that for `int` or `Pointer*` it means having some undefined value (garbage, likely)
- If a class has no default constructor (ie a constructor that can be invoked without any argument, either because it takes none or they all have default values), then it cannot be default constructed
- If there are several constructors, then the "best match" is selected depending on the list of arguments, like for regular function calls

*In your case, `worker` has two constructors, a default constructor `worker()` and another constructor `worker(std::string name, int hours)`; neither completely initialize the class which is WEIRD. Start by defining a single constructor which sets EVERY data member (though it may set some to a default value without deducing said value from an argument).*

*In your case, you attempt to call a constructor on an existing object (`arr[1].worker(name, hours)`): this is nonsensical as the constructor's role is to create the object. Read on.*

**Inheritance**

Inheritance is used to *extend* a class. It should mostly be used in situations that satisfy the Liskov Substitution Principle: ie, in all instances, the derived class behavior should fulfill any guarantee the base class gave.

In general:

- you should only try to extend a class that was meant to be: the base class should have at least a `virtual` method.
- a class with at least one `virtual` method should also have a `virtual` destructor (note: the destructor of a class inheriting from at least one class with a `virtual` destructor is implicitly `virtual`)

Example:

```
class ISalaried {
public:
    virtual ~Salaried() {}

    virtual int getSalary(int hours, int overtime) const = 0;
};

class Employee: public ISalaried {
public:
    Employee(std::string name, int rate): name(name), rate(rate) {}

    // implicitly declared by the compiler for you
    // virtual ~Employee() {}

    // override is specific to C++11, if your compiler does not recognize it,
    // leave it off.
    virtual int getSalary(int hours, int overtime) const override {
        return rate * (hours + overtime);
    }

private:
    std::string name;
    int rate;
};
```

By default, a derived class constructor will invoke the base class default constructor; this can be changed by invoking it directly from the initializer list:

```
class Derived: public Base {
public:
    Derived(): Base(200, "42") {} // invokes a constructor of Base
};
```

If the base class does not have a default constructor, it is necessary.

*In your case, it means that both your derived classes should pass the name and hours to your `worker` constructor from their own constructor.*

Also, a derived class cannot access its base class `private` members. You can either make said members `public` or define a `public` getter member function in the base class which takes no argument and return the value of the member (one getter for each parameter).

Another alternative is for the base class to have no member (only present an interface).

**Goal**

There is another issue here, memory, however handling memory correctly is a completely separate subject and we are going way past our complexity budget already.

Therefore, I will instead give you a goal: the `main` function so written should compile, change your `worker`, `contract` and `part_time` classes to make it so.

```
int main() {
    contract c0("XYZ", 10);
    contract c1("XYZ", 10);
    part_time pt0("XYZ", 10);
    part_time pt1("XYZ", 10);

    worker* array[] = { &c0, &c1, &pt0, &pt1 };

    for (size_t i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
        array[i]->getsal(20);
    }
}
```